# Changing the image of a button in a different layout

Tags: java, android

I'm a bit stumped on this. I have a button in an 'Upgrades' activity that will change the image of an imagebutton in my Main Activity.

How would I go about doing this?

I simply want the image of that button to change/update when the upgrades button is clicked.

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can [**help with certain problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [**put some efforts**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [**(re)search**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KlC2WdDPCKzT8gfFz72QDw). Read [**how to ask perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0):

When button is pressed run this:

```
yourImagebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourImage);
```

YourImage must located in drawable folder.